# Why is $S^{2k-1} = S(\mathbb{C}^k)$ true?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Why is $S^{2k-1} = S(\mathbb{C}^k)$ true? Note $S(\mathbb{C}^k) =$ {$z \in \mathbb{C}^k$ such that $|| z ||=1 $}.

My work: I just tried a few examples like $k=1$, then $S^1 =S(\mathbb{C}^1)$. Then $S^1$ is a circle of radius $1$ and $S(\mathbb{C}^1)$ = {$a+bi \in \mathbb{C}^1$ such that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$}? Am I missing something? I think now I need to prove there is a homeomorphism between them? This is a part of a bigger proof so let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez oh I guess it is only {-1,1}, right?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I changed it! Now is it correct?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez oh my god, can't believe I didn't think of that, haha. Thank you very much!!